# Capture exactly 2 words from string

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regex to parse a command that looks like this:

```
!hello foo bar
```

I would like to capture `foo` and `bar`. If the command is passed anything but 2 arguments then I want the regex to fail.

Here's my regex so far:

```
^!hello (.*)$
```

I know that `{2}` can be used to limit the amount captured, but I'm not sure exactly how to use it in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Should this fail or succed? `!hello "foo bar" foz`

Comment: @Wrikken fail. It should take two words, no quotes. Thanks

Comment: you can simply use explode

Comment: `^!hello (?:\w+) (?:\w+)$`

Comment: But are there restrictions on what characters the arguments contain? Must they be only a-z, or a-z0-9, or more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the greedy `(.*)`, I would recommend using something more specific like `\w+` to match one or more "word" characters. Since whitespace may be insignificant, separate them with `\s+`.  Rather than trying to use `{2}`, since you expect exactly two separated by whitespace, it is easier to spell each group out literally as `\w+` with the whitespace requirement in between.

```
^!hello\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)$
```

If you don't actually need to reuse the arguments, remove the `()`.

```
^!hello\s+\w+\s+\w+$

$pattern = '/^!hello\s+\w+\s+\w+$/';
echo preg_match($pattern, '!hello foo bar');
// 1
echo preg_match($pattern, '!hello foo bar baz');
// 0
echo preg_match($pattern, '!hello "foo bar" baz');
// 0
// Note a numeric argument matches \w+... If that isn't allowed
// you should use [A-Za-z]+ instead or just [a-z]+ and add the /i flag
echo preg_match($pattern, '!hello 123 baz');
// 1
echo preg_match($pattern, '!hello a$1 baz');
// 0
```

Answer (score 1):

.* captures everything, including whitespace. What you want to do is capture a run of one or more characters that can be anything **but** whitespace, then some whitespace, then another run of non-whitespace characters.

The way to capture this using regex syntax is:

`^!hello\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$`

Note the use of + instead of * - you must have at least one space between the words, 0 spaces is not acceptable. Each word must also be at least one character. This also allows a run of trailing whitespace.

Note that \S will recognize anything that is not whitespace. This means that

`hello %__ second_word`

would match. If you want to only match word characters for the words, use \w instead of \S (see the [HP manual for definitions of the different [generic character types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), or instructions for creating your own [character class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).